# Problems with plpython3u in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, python3

I have some problems with plpython3u in PostgreSQL. Who can explain how to install the **Python 3.x extension** correctly for Windows 10 and use this extension in PostgreSQL with some code examples?

I can create the extension plpython3u, but when I write a function and then try to start, I get a disconnection:

[image: Error connection]

Query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a int)
  RETURNS int
AS $$
    return a
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```